# Invalid character in the given encoding when parsing rss feed

Tags: xml, vb.net, character-encoding, rss

I'm parsing rss feed form another server and show in Repeater.
But there is error: Invalid character in the given encoding.
The code is follow:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Create a WebRequest
        Dim rssReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.freelancer.com/rss/affiliatejob_mamboking_NET.xml")
        'Create a Proxy
        Dim px As New WebProxy("http://www.freelancer.com/rss/affiliatejob_mamboking_NET.xml", True)
        'Assign the proxy to the WebRequest
        rssReq.Proxy = px
        'Set the timeout in Seconds for the WebRequest
        rssReq.Timeout = 5000
        Try
            'Get the WebResponse
            Dim rep As WebResponse = rssReq.GetResponse()
            'Read the Response in a XMLTextReader
            Dim xtr As New XmlTextReader(rep.GetResponseStream())
            'Create a new DataSet
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            'Read the Response into the DataSet
            ds.ReadXml(xtr)
            'Bind the Results to the Repeater
            rssFreelance.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            rssFreelance.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

When I see source of the xml it's show utf-8 encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.freelancer.com/content/rss.xsl" ?><rss version="2.0" xmlns:coop="http://www.google.com/coop/namespace">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Web
WebUtility.HtmlDecode(response)
```

Where **response** is the actual text you want to decode, **the description** or **the title**.